# NavigationDrawer - Different toolbar for each fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I have an app with a single Activity(MainActivity) and a Navigation Drawer. The navigation drawer, of course, opens the fragments in the activity. The problem I am facing is that I have already linked the MainActivity toolbar to the ActionToggle (hamburger) when I created an object of the ActionToggle. So the MainActivity toolbar shows in all fragments, but I want different toolbar XML for each fragments. If I want to hide the MainActivity toolbar in the fragments, the ActionToggle (hamburger) will also get hidden.

Please, how can I have different toolbar for each fragment, with the MainActivity ActionToggle in all the toolbars?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have expected the question to be clearer, but as I understand it, I can help you in the following way.

-If you want to change your toolbar from within different fragments,
below code block can help you.

```
Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

-If you just want to change the toolbar properties such as the title, you can use the code block below.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("title");
```